# Start UIStepper from initial value

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift2, uistepper

I have a UIStepper connected to a UITextField. The stepper goes from 0 to 13. Whenever I click the stepper on the plus, I get "1" . I want to start with a 0. I tried many codes, but none of them worked, such as:

```
@IBAction func stepperAc(sender: AnyObject) {
     if textField.text == "" {
     Stepper.value = 0
     textField.text = 0
   }
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func stepperAc(sender: UIStepper) {
 if textField.text == "" {
     sender.value = 0
     textField.text = 0
   }
}
```

Comment: If i do so, then the stepper would be able to go to -1. And i want 0 to be my minimum value

Comment: You are right. I believe `stepperAc` is a action handler on your stepper. why don't you do it like `sender.value = 0`? @user3902533

Comment: Additionally, if you are sure on caller for `stepperAc` you should not use `AnyObject`. Try with my updated post.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I already had a func eith sender:UIStepper, but didnt try the sender.value=0